# Doctrine with large datasets

Tags: php, memory, doctrine

Does anyone have experience using Doctrine with large datasets? I have an import script that uses Doctrine and it uses way too much memory. The speed isn't a huge problem but the memory usage is. Does anyone have any tips for keeping Doctrine's memory usage down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Doctrine 1.2 at least, freeing objects after use frees up memory, which is recommended for long-running scripts:

```
$my_object->free();
```

There's a few tips on improving performance at the end of the official guide:

http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/improving-performance/en